# CanCanCan, Doorkeeper and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When I try to write tests in RSpec I get an error

```
CanCan::AuthorizationNotPerformed:
   This action failed the check_authorization because it does not authorize_resource. Add skip_authorization_check to bypass this check.
```

Although CanCanCan is configured and the controller has

```
before_action: doorkeeper_authorize!
```

Tests pass only when I specify in the controller even

```
skip_authorization_check
```

Answer (score 1):

It was necessary to add an action to the configuration of the CanCanCan authorization

Comment: I have the same problem though two my actions without access tokens (on 401) pass. Idk why. Does anyone know?

Comment: Anyway big thanks for clarifying problem, it helped!